# SQL Server truncating stored procedure statement from node-mssql into 65535 characters with line breaks

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2019 instance which stores images as `VARBINARY` columns - photo and signature. I created a stored procedure which accepts photo, signature, `<uniqueidentifier>`, `<capturedate>`, and two metadata (integer) flags and inserts them in the table person-images.

I have an node-express API which accepts these fields - the pictures are in base64 originally - converts the images to buffer then to calls stored procedure using `mode-mssql` as follows:

```
if (doccount == null || doccount < 1){
// connect to database 
   (async function(){
       try {
          let pool = await sql.connect(config)
          let request = await pool.request()
          .input('id', sql.Int, uniqueid)
          .input('photo', sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX), photo)
          .input('signature', sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX), signature)
          .input('signatureexception', sql.Int, signatureexception)
          .input('isminor', sql.Int, isminor)
          .input('capturedate', sql.DateTime, capturedate)
          .execute('update-images', (err, result)=>{
              if (result.returnvalue && result.recordset && result.returnvalue == 200){
                  res.send({
                      status:"SUCCESS",
                      data: {
                          isUpdated: "TRUE",
                          registrant:result.recordset
                      }
                  })
                  sql.close();
              } else {
                  console.log(err);
                  let response = {
                      status:"FAIL",
                      errorCode: "UPDATE_FAIL",
                      errorDescription: "Record could not be updated"
                  };
                  res.status(404).send(response);
                  sql.close(); 
              }
          })
      } catch (err){
          console.log(err)
          let response = {
              status:"FAIL",
              errorCode: err.name,
              errorDescription:err.message
          }
          res.send(response);
          sql.close();
      }
})()
```

This fails with an error that proxy server could not handle the request. When I monitored using SQL Server Profiler, the application connects successfully and converts the syntax as follows:

```
exec update-images
@uniqueid=<random_number>,
@photo= <binary-data>,
@signature = <binary-data>
@signatureexception=0,
@isminor=0,
@capturedate='2023-03-01 00:00:00'
```

The issue seems to be that the converted binary-data is broken down with line breaks every time 65535 characters/ bytes are reached which effectively breaks the stored procedure not the SQL Server side. If I use SSMS and remove the line breaks the stored procedure executes perfectly.

How do I manage this? The signature by itself exceeds 65535 bytes...

Comment: You write that you convert them to buffer, a buffer usually has a max size. you might wanna convert them to a binary array or whatever nodejs uses

Comment: `sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX)` parameters should work if you're using JavaScript `Buffer` objects correctly. How are you setting up the `photo` and `signature` values?

Comment: @siggemannen According to the node mssql documentation [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#request, in the section JS Data Type To SQL Data Type Map, Node Buffer maps to SQL Varbinary.

@AlwaysLearning Photo and Signature come in as base64 string then I use
`let photo = Buffer.from(req.body.photo,'base64');`to convert to Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

After testing with various queries being called by stored procedures, I noticed it happens every time the parameters with values exceeds 65535 characters regardless of whether the variables themselves can contain more than this length i.e. varbinary(max). When I call the queries directly (not using stored procedure) with the same values everything works perfectly. **Ultimately, I decided to call execute the queries sequentially from the code as a workaround**. My theory is that SQL drivers stores the entire stored procedure statement - including values - in a varchar(max) variable which has an inherent limit of 65535. This makes it impossible to execute stored procedures where the values of a varbinary(max) may exceed this inherent limit. Once the limit is reached, SQL creates consecutive varchar variables to store the overflow. The overflow value no longer contains the execution syntax resulting in an error being thrown by SQL.